# how to monitor a server (mapserver)

Tags: web-applications, mapserver

¿how can I know that things have happened rafters or on my server?, I've had a problem with a server in my care and that can not be causing these errors because they are not replaced an archives of any kind and no has done nothing wrong in applying for any suggestions

http://obtra.univalle.edu.co/obtra/index.php?site=carto

these are the errors:

Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadSymbolSet(): First token must be SYMBOLSET, this doesn't look like a symbol file. in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 25

Warning: Failed to open map file obtra_1.map in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 25

Fatal error: Call to a member function getLayerByName() on a non-object in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 33

thanks for any response

Comment: I would start by looking at `/var/www/obtra/vcauca.php`, at line 25.

Comment: vcauca.php  its  good   not  modificated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from MapServer version 5.4, symbolset files must be enclosed with `SYMBOLSET ... END` tags:

```
SYMBOLSET

 SYMBOL
 ...
 END

 SYMBOL
 ...
 END

END
```

Check that the symbolset file you are using is enclosed with this tags. The other two errors are related to the first one, as Mapscript is unable to parse the map file and fetch the map object.