# downgrade mapserver

Tags: ubuntu, mapserver

a question, as I can uninstall and install mapserver an older version, since I is causing roughly following error and I think is the version of the same

Warning: [MapServer Error]: msLoadSymbolSet(): First token must be SYMBOLSET, this doesn't look like a symbol file. in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 25

Warning: Failed to open map file obtra_1.map in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 25

Fatal error: Call to a member function getLayerByName() on a non-object in /var/www/obtra/vcauca.php on line 33

this in ubuntu 8.04 if it is not possible please where I can get an older version that I recommended to avoid mistakes and to update the system.
thanks for your suggestions and answers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225843/how-to-monitor-a-server-mapserver/2227574#2227574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only edit the file symbolset.sys

SYMBOLSET

SYMBOL
 ...
END